# The inputted data is not written to the file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct, logic-error

I've been trying to find the error but the code still not working, I'm using struct function and files to save all the inputted data, but when I run the program, I found out that the inputted data from option 1 (case 1/void input) was not written to the parking3 file. Since the data are not written to the file so the option 2 and 3 which for read data from the parking3 file couldn't work, I am not sure how to fix it, but here is the full code for more understanding :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<process.h>

struct car
 {
    //public member function can access any private, protected and public member of it's class//
    string VehicleNo; 
    string area[4][4] = {{"A1","A2","A3","A4"},{"B1","B2","B3","B4"},{"C1","C2","C3","C4"},{"D1","D2","D3","D4"}};
    float Hours;
    char  DriverName[30],Time[50];
    int VIP,NONVIP;
 };
    car Parking [10];

    void input() //fetch data needed from the user
    { 
        
        system("cls"); //to clear the screen
        int i;
        ofstream outfile;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter the name of driver : ";
        cin>>Parking[i].DriverName;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter the car no : ";
        cin>>Parking[i].VehicleNo;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter the no of hours of stay : ";
        cin>>Parking[i].Hours;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tParking area available : "<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t_________________________________\n";
        cout<<"\t\t| Area  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|\n";
        cout<<"\t\t| floor |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|       |  2  |  2  |  2  |  2  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|       |  3  |  3  |  3  |  3  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|       |  4  |  4  |  4  |  4  |\n";
        cout<<"\t\t|_______|_____|_____|_____|_____|"<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter parking area you want to park : ";
        cin>>Parking[i].area[i][i];  
        
        if(Parking[i].Hours<15)
          { 
           if(Parking[i].area[i][i] =="A1" || Parking[i].area[i][i] =="A2"|| Parking[i].area[i][i] =="A3" || Parking[i].area[i][i] =="A4")
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\t\tParking slot available. You can park your car.";
            }
            
            else if (Parking[i].area[i][i]=="B1"|| Parking[i].area[i][i]=="B2" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="B3" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="B4")
            {
                
                cout<<"\n\n\t\tParking slot available. You can park your car.";
            }
            
            else if (Parking[i].area[i][i]=="C1"|| Parking[i].area[i][i]=="C2" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="C3" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="C4")
            {
                
                cout<<"\n\n\t\tParking slot available. You can park your car.";
            }
            
            else if (Parking[i].area[i][i]=="D1"|| Parking[i].area[i][i]=="D2" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="D3" || Parking[i].area[i][i]=="D4")
            {
                
                cout<<"\n\n\t\tParking not available. Please try another slot";
            }
            
          }
          
        else 
        cout<<"Reached time limit for workers parking time"<<endl;
        
        
    }

 void calculate() //function to calculate parking fees
    {
        int i;  
        cout<<"\n\t\n\tAre you registered as a V.I.P?: (y/n) ";
        cin>>Parking[i].VIP;
        if(Parking[i].VIP=='y')
      {
        system("cls");
        Parking[i].VIP=Parking[i].Hours*20;
        cout<<"\n\t\n\t[VIP] The total of parking fees: ";
        cout<<"RM "<<Parking[i].VIP; //calculate payment for vip member
      }
    else 
      {
        system("cls");
        Parking[i].NONVIP=Parking[i].Hours*25;
        cout<<"\n\t\n\t[NON-VIP] The total of parking fees: ";
        cout<<"RM "<<Parking[i].NONVIP; //calculate payment for non-vip member
        
      }
    }   
    void output() //details statement to the user
    {
        int i;
        cout<<"\n\n\tThe Car position in parking lot : "<<Parking[i].area[i][i]<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tThe Driver Name : "<<Parking[i].DriverName<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tThe Car No : "<<Parking[i].VehicleNo<<endl;
        cout<<"\n\n\t\tThe Hours Of Stay : " <<Parking[i].Hours<<endl;
    }


int main() // main function for the menu 
{
    int login();
    login(); // using login function
    int choice,i;
    while(1) 
    {
     system("cls"); //clear the screen
         //printing menu page statement
          cout<<"\t\t                  _________________\n";
         cout<<"\t\t              _.-'_____  _________ _`.\n";
         cout<<"\t\t            .` ,'      ||         | `.`.\n";
         cout<<"\t\t          .` ,'        ||         |   `.`.\n";
         cout<<"\t\t        .`  /          ||         |  ,' ] `....___\n";
         cout<<"\t\t      _`__.'''''''''''''''''''''''`''''''''|..___ `-.._\n";
         cout<<"\t\t    .'                  [='                '     `'-.._`.\n";
         cout<<"\t\t ,:/.'''''''''''''''''''||'''''''''''''''''||''''''''''''\' ";
         cout<<"\t\t\n  //||    _..._         ||                 ||   _..._  |)| \n";
         cout<<"\t\t /|//   ,',---.`.       ||                 || .',---.`, |";
         cout<<"\t\t\n(':/   //' .-. `\\      \\_________________////' .-. `\\ |_)";
         cout<<"\t\t\n `-...'||  '-'  ||________,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,__.'||  '-'  ||-' \n";
         cout<<"\t\t       '.'.___.','                           '.'.___.',' \n";
         cout<<"\t\t         '-.m.-'                               '-.m.-'\n";
                    
         cout << "\n\n\t\t ====== CAR PARKING RESERVATION SYSTEM ======";
         cout <<"\n\n                                          ";
         cout<<" \n\t\t\t======================";
         cout << "\n\n\t\t\t  1. Arrival of a Car"; //input new data from new car
         cout << "\n\n\t\t\t  2. Total no of cars Arrived"; //view total cars arrived
         cout << "\n\n\t\t\t  3. Total parking charges of all cars with details"; //view payment data for all car
         cout << "\n\n\t\t\t  4. Exit Program"; //exit the program
         cout<<" \n\t\t\t======================";
         cout << "\n\n";
         cout << "\t\t\t Select Your Choice ::"; //admin input choice either 1,2,3,4 or 5
         cin>>choice;
     switch(choice) //using switch structure
     {
      case 1 : //choice 1: car arrival
        {       
            char proceed;
            cout<<"\nDo You Want to continue==Yes(y)/No(n) ";
            cin>>proceed;
            while(proceed=='y')
            {   
                ofstream outfile;
                outfile.open("parking3.txt");
                outfile<<"CAR PARKING SYSTEM\n";
                input();
                outfile<<"\n\n\tThe Car position in parking lot : "<<Parking[i].area[i][i]<<endl;
                outfile<<"\n\n\t\tThe Driver Name : "<<Parking[i].DriverName<<endl;
                outfile<<"\n\n\t\tThe Car No : "<<Parking[i].VehicleNo<<endl;
                outfile<<"\n\n\t\tThe Hours Of Stay : " <<Parking[i].Hours<<endl;
                outfile.close(); 
                
            }
           
        }
       
       case 2 : //choice 2: viewing total car arrived
        {
           system("cls");
           cout << "\n\n\t\t== Viewing Record in the Parking Database ==";
           cout << "\n";
           int record;
           cout<<"How many record you want to see?";
           cin>>record;
           ifstream infile; //reading data from the file
           infile.open("parking3.txt");
           for(int i=0;i<record;i++)
           {
               system("cls");
               cout << "\n";
               infile>>Parking[i].area[i][i];
               infile>>Parking[i].DriverName;
               infile>>Parking[i].VehicleNo[i];
               infile>>Parking[i].Hours;
               output(); // calling function output to print statement
               system("PAUSE");
               cout<<endl;
        
               
           }
           infile.close();
          
        }   
       
       case 3: //choice 3: details of parking charges of all cars
        {
           ifstream infile; //reading from the file
           infile.open("parking3.txt");
           int record;
           cout<<"How many record you want to see?";
           cin>>record;
           for(int i=0;i<record;i++)
           {
             cout << "\n";
             calculate(); //call function calculate
             output(); //call function output
             cout<<"\n";
             cout<<endl;     
           }
          infile.close();
          
        }
        
        case 4: //exit the program
        {
            system("CLS");
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
           
        default : //default option if admin choose option other than 1,2,3,4 or 5
        {
           cout<<"\n\n\t\t Invalid input";
           cout<<"\n\n\t\tPress Enter to continue";
        }
    
     }
     getch();
     
     
    }
}
```

Please help me to fix it

Comment: I don't see any error checking for whether `outfile.open` worked.

Comment: `int i; in>>Parking[i].DriverName;` This code exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing uninitialized variable `i`.

Comment: This is quite a lot of code to write before testing something basic like file output. Did you have a working program that you then refactored into functions? Please code a little at a time, and test often. This is especially important when you are struggling to understand C++ language fundamentals such as variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to throw this code away, it is unfixable. Here's one example (this error seems to be repeated multiple times), from the function `input`

```
    int i;
    ofstream outfile;
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tEnter the name of driver : ";
    cin>>Parking[i].DriverName;
```

What do you think the value of the variable `i` is here when you use it in the line `cin>>Parking[i].DriverName;`? The answer is that it doesn't have one. What will this do to your program? Probably crash it.

Now you have written a lot of code, and it seems that none of it is working. This can only be because you've written all that code without doing any testing. This is the wrong way to write software. Write a little bit of code (literally a few lines), test them until you are sure they work, and then write a few more lines. It's the only way to write software. Writing lots of code without any testing always fails and if you are a beginner, leaves you stuck with no idea what has gone wrong.